# blackberry gps getting current Location Address?

Tags: blackberry

Hi i am new to blackberry application development.I want to get current gps location detail.I had successfully got the latitude and longitude but i dont know how to get the current address.can any one give me a sample?Pls thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is called "Reverse Geocoding."  RIM has an [example of exactly how to do this](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11944/Reverse_geocode_API_example_869857_11.jsp) on the BB platform (well, one way to do it anyway).

Comment: how can i check the value ?inside that runnable thread no field is allowed like(labelfield,textfield) how can i check addrinfo value? please reply me

Comment: it sounds like you should do some looking into the use of threading in BB applications.  For example, you might see Blackberry UI Threading - The Very Basics: http://www.thinkingblackberry.com/archives/182

Answer (score 3):

You can use Google map to resolve your issue, Google map will return a JSON (or XML) according to your choice if you request with a lattitude and longitude.

The url is: `http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?json&ll="+_lattitude+","+_longitude`

This will return all the details of the given latitude and longitude in JSON format,And you have to parse the JSON returned by Google map.

You can use the below code:

```java
private void getLocationFromGoogleMaps() {
    try {
        StreamConnection s = null;
        InputStream iStream = null;        
        s=(StreamConnection)javax.microedition.io.Connector.open("http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?json&ll="+_lattitude+","+_longitude+getConnectionStringForGoogleMap());//&deviceside=false&ConnectionType=mds-public"

        HttpConnection con = (HttpConnection)s; 
        con.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "//text");
         int status = con.getResponseCode();
         if (status == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK)
         {
             iStream=s.openInputStream();                    
             int len=(int) con.getLength();
             byte[] data = new byte[8000];                    
             byte k;
             String result="";
             while((k = (byte)iStream.read()) != -1) {
                 result = result+(char)k;
             }                  
             try {
                  JSONObject jsonObjectMapData=new JSONObject(result);                                                    
                  JSONArray  jsonaryPlaceMark = jsonObjectMapData.getJSONArray("Placemark");
                  JSONObject address= jsonaryPlaceMark.getJSONObject(0);
                 String placeName=address.getString("address");
                 if(placeName!=null)
                     lblLoc.setText(address.getString("address"));
                 else
                     lblLoc.setText("Location information currently unavilable");
             } catch (Exception e) {
                 lblLoc.setText("location information Currently Unavilable");
             }
         }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        lblLoc.setText("location information Currently Unavilable");
    }        
}
```

Note: I use a **FacebookBlackBerrySDK-0.3.5-src** to parse JSON or you can XML aslo.